Qt Application rendering in Yocto beaglebone Black
I am building Qt application for beaglebone black board using Yocto project. I have two UI pages, In MainWindow designed icon which is login button by selecting it navigates Dialog page where i have some icons and back button. I have connected My board to Touchscreen and when i boot My Qt application is coming in the startup. then i got to know that, in my application when Dialog page is Displayed over MainWindow if i click anywhere in MainWindow, Dialog page was going behind MainWindow, so i tried below code to resolve it.
void MainWindow::showDialog()
{

Dialog *dialog = new Dialog(this); 

dialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);

dialog->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal); 
dialog->show();
}

Now when i booted this code I am able to login once when i go-back and login once again login button and other functionalities also not working, window is freezed.Please let me know How to solve this..?

Please provide a [mre]. Also, if you used QDialog and its exec() or open() functions, it will automatically be set as modal.

I have added code which is used to keep Dialog page top of MainWindow until Dialog page is closed.

Sorry but that's not a [mre]. Please read the above link and follow its indications more carefully.
